# Ruby on Rails Generating Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, scaffold

Is there a way to generate the views separately using the rails generate command? I would also be willing to install a gem to accomplish that task f one exists. Basically the scaffolding command gives me too much and I would rather code my controller by hand. However, writing the index view with a table for the records would not be very efficient.

Comment: Because it is a large table with quite a few columns writing that by hand seems to defeat some of the purpose of rails generators

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114866/create-rails-views-only-after-controllers-and-models-are-already-created - your question could be taken to mean that you want *only* views to be generated, without touching anything that already exists, which the answers below won't actually accomplish.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can generate the controller and the view using the controller generator.

```
rails g controller controllername new create
```

This will create actions `new` and `create` with their corresponding views.

You still need to set up your routes manually with this.

Comment: How do you specify a model/controller to generate the views for?

Comment: Views are generated for the controller.  `rails g controller pages about contact` will create the files `controllers/pages_controller.rb`, `views/pages/about.html.erb`, `views/pages/contact.html.erb`

Comment: what if i just want to add an action to the existing controller and want the view page to be created automatically

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid There is not a generator for it as far as I know.  It is fairly trivial to do manually.  Create the view.html.erb file,  add a new method to the controller then update your routes.

Comment: You can use it https://github.com/patshaughnessy/view_mapper to generate views based on models.
script/generate view_for office --view auto_complete:address

Comment: In Rails 4, the routes are generated automatically.

Comment: This creates the controllers and the views but they are empty.. No working code in there..

Comment: if app has been created only for API (rails new api_app_name --api -T), will not create any view, helper, assets & test.

Answer (score 11):

One particular situation is when you want to add a ***new*** view to an existing controller.

In that case, just use the regular command, but be careful to say `'n'` every time prompted in order to not overwrite existing files.

For example, adding a view called `'invite'` to an existing controller named `'projects'`:

```
smith@ubuntuSrv16DEV4:~/railsapps/project_manager$ rails -v
Rails 5.1.4
smith@ubuntuSrv16DEV4:~/railsapps/project_manager$ rails generate controller projects invite
Running via Spring preloader in process 46253
    conflict  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
Overwrite /home/smith/railsapps/project_manager/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
       route  get 'projects/invite'
      invoke  erb
       exist    app/views/projects
      create    app/views/projects/invite.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
    conflict    test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb
  Overwrite /home/smith/railsapps/project_manager/test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip    test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
   identical    app/helpers/projects_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
   identical      app/assets/javascripts/projects.coffee
      invoke    scss
    conflict      app/assets/stylesheets/projects.scss
    Overwrite /home/smith/railsapps/project_manager/app/assets/stylesheets/projects.scss? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip      app/assets/stylesheets/projects.scss
smith@ubuntuSrv16DEV4:~/railsapps/project_manager$
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Comment: Yea this. Except in Apr 2022, using Rails 6.1.5, I had to supply the flag `--skip-collision-check`. So the whole command would read something like `rails g controller controller_name first_view_name second_view_name --skip-collision-check`. The flag is a bit of a misnomer as it *does* end up asking you whether to override or keep existing files. It skips the collision check on the payments controller as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

the first part is the name of the model/controller, the second part are the actions.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned by sameers there was post that showed how to just generate a the views. It will create all the views for your model using the rails default templates which is very handy.

If like me you want something a little more customizable you can achieve the following.

You can create your own generator so you have something like this.

rails generate view NAME VIEW [options]

To achieve this you need to do the following.

`rails generate generator view`

This will generate a few files for you in lib/generators/view/ folder.

Open the view_generator.rb file and add the following code.

```
class ViewGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)
  argument :name, type: :string
  argument :action, type: :string

  def generate_view
    template "#{file_name}.html.erb", "app/views/#{folder_name}/#{file_name}.html.erb"
  end

  private

  def folder_name
    name.underscore
  end

  def file_name
    action.underscore
  end

  def type
    name.titleize.singularize
  end

  def down_type
    name.downcase.singularize
  end

  def render_form
    "<%= render 'form', #{down_type}: @#{down_type} %>"
  end

  def render_link_back
    "<%= link_to 'Back', #{folder_name}_path %>"
  end
end</pre>
```

Next you need to create the file that we are using actual template used in generate_view method.

Using the action new as example, create a filelib/generators/view/new.html.erb and add the following.

```
<h1>New <%= type %></h1>

<%= render_form %>

<%= render_link_back %>
```

Customize the template view as much as you want. You will need to add the _form.html.erb as well. Add any additional variables and logic in your view_generator.rb file and you are done.

It's more work but can be worth it if you find yourself generating similar views all the time.

Best use case I can think of for this approach is if you white label your platform and need to generate multiple files for a clients profile.