# Scaffolding only the view files in Rails. Possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After its initial construction, I have added a couple of columns to my `Books` database table. As I actually want my views to reflect and show the fields related to all these new added columns I figured it'd be cheaper to just delete everything that's inside the `views/books/` folder, and have some scaffold code regenerate it from the ground up. I don't want to delete either the controller or the model file, as both already contain some logic I'd like to keep. I'm fine editing those files myself on a on-need basis.

How to accomplish the task?

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4333530/130758 I can see `scaffold` seems to have options for both controllers and models, but unfortunately, not for views. Am I bound to have to do this grunt work by myself? I'm aware I can just create a new git branch, delete the + model + views and regenerate all of them, copy paste the the views back into the original branch and I'm ready to go, but I'd prefer a more scientific approach, whenever possible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Rails views (only) after controllers and models are already created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114866/create-rails-views-only-after-controllers-and-models-are-already-created)

Answer (score 82):

I know this question is probably too old to help the person who originally asked the question, but I'd like to point out that the default `scaffold` generator calls the `erb:scaffold` generator to generate the ERB files. So, you can do:

```
rails g erb:scaffold Book
```

This will return:

```
create  app/views/books
create  app/views/books/index.html.erb
create  app/views/books/edit.html.erb
create  app/views/books/show.html.erb
create  app/views/books/new.html.erb
create  app/views/books/_form.html.erb
```

Comment: And my personal favorite `rails g slim:scaffold Book`