# Which rails command creates index.html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm maintaining an old, undocumented rails application. The app/views/application directory has an index.html.haml file, but the public directory doesn't have an index.html file. Which rails command do I need to run to generate the index file in the public directory? I'm using apache as my web server and passenger as my app server.

Answer (score 3):

`rails generate` command generates controllers or scaffolds for you. If you want to create a view, you need to generate a corresponding controller in the controllers folder, plus a route in the route.rb file with the views to show on the web in views folder. I can help you better if I knew the exact problem you are trying to solve. You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614083/ruby-on-rails-generating-views) for generating controller and view as a reference.